# The best way to apply a git patch via Ansible

Tags: git, ansible

I need to deploy a bunch of Ubuntu servers in the same way, so I thought of using ansible instead of doing it manually each time I need a new one.

One of the things I need to do is to git clone an upstream repo, and the apply a custom patch to it.  I was hoping to save the patch in my ansible directory under files/, but there doesn't seem to be a "git apply" function in the git ansible module.  What's the best practise of doing something like this?

Some options:

1. Run my own git repo with a branch including my patch.  This would work, but I would have to maintain my own git repo somewhere and make sure my servers have access/permissions to it.  It would be nice if all the configurations are kept in my ansible directory instead of relying on another git repo I have to maintain.
2. Use shell or command module.  Easiest to get working, but I won't be able to re-run the playbook.
3. Other suggestions?

Comment: Can you apply the patch to the `master` branch of the repo which you are cloning?

Comment: Since I'm cloning an upstream /  public repo, no I won't be able to do that.

Comment: i'd create another branch, and just switch the `git` module of ansible to `version: {{ the_version }}` where `the_version` is your branch.

Comment: So are you saying that you don't have write permissions to the repo?

Comment: if you don't have access, then fork it.

Comment: @digitalsky how about using the `shell` or `script` [command modules in ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/list_of_commands_modules.html) and after a successful `git clone`, run `cd <local-clone-dir>; git am <filename.patch>` ? There's always a chance that the patch may not apply on the latest version of the cloned source which can be detected by the return code of the git commands. Usually `git` returns **`0`** upon success and **`1`** upon failure.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses.  I would like to emphasize having another repo / branch is mentioned in my OP as option 1, but I'm trying to find a way to get this working without having my own repo / fork / branch due to maintenance / access issues.

Comment: @TheCodeArtist: Thanks for the suggestion - I'm planning on doing something similar for option 2, but I don't think I would be able to re-run the playbook that way because it would try to re-apply the patch.

Comment: @digitalsky so in your script, add `git log --oneline | grep <commit-title>` before attempting `git am` to detect whether the patch has already been applied. For traceability, remember to add echo/prints like `Checking for patch <xyz>...`, `Patch <xyz> already applied. Skipping...` etc. to log the progress and path-followed to help debug when something ever fails in the automated production instance.

Comment: @TheCodeArtist:  What I have now is task1 to copy the patch over to the remote, and register "variable".  Then task2 does the "git apply" (using commnad module) when "variable.changed".  That's on the assumption that whenever the copy is needed, then i need to run git apply.  But I like your idea better. thanks!  Although ideally the git module would handle something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use the [**Ansible `script` module**](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/script_module.html).

Write a shell script that attempts to patch a git repository with a local patch.

> Handle the various possibilities like :
>
> - being invoked during a cookbook re-run.
> - the latest upstream source already containing the identical change as the local patch.
> - the local patch no longer being applicable on the latest upstream source.

---

#### A sample shell script template for the above :

```
# sync the local copy with latest changes from the upstream git repository.

# TODO : Check here for return code of "git am" for failure.
#
# If <filename.patch> already applied, then :
# - This is probably a cookbook re-run,
#   or
# - The latest upstream source now comes with the patch applied.
# Display/Log an info message about this and skip to the end of the script.

# Patch latest upstream source with a local patch
echo "Attempting to apply <filename.patch>..." 
cd <local-clone-dir>
git am <filename.patch>

# TODO : Check here for return code of "git am" for failure.
#
# In case <filename.patch> no longer applies 
# to the latest version of the source from upstream repo,
# display/log the error and abort immediately.
    
echo "Successfully applied <filename.patch>." 

# Continue with rest of the tasks.
```

Comment: I would add to your list of possibilities "Git user.name and user.email not being configured" since the git am command will attempt to do a commit after applying the patch